# pip3 installed without pip

Tags: python, bash, macos, pip, homebrew

I have pip3 installed from when I installed Python3 through Homebrew. But now when I use pip3 to install things, I get the following message:

> You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.2.3 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

But when I use `pip install --upgrade pip`, I get the following message:

> -bash: pip: command not found

I'm not sure what the precise terminology is, but should I be "linking" the pip command to pip3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade pip3 as follows to avoid the confusion between `pip` and `pip3`:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```